Proof that $\sup AB=(\sup A)(\sup B)$

Prove that $\sup AB=(\sup A)(\sup B)$, where $AB$ is the product of the sets and $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R^+}$.

Since $A,B$ are bounded above, $\sup A$ and $\sup B$ exist. Let $\alpha = \sup A$ and $\beta = \sup B$. This implies $\forall a \in A$ and $\forall b \in B$ $a \leq \alpha$ and $b \leq \beta$. Then $ab \leq \alpha\beta$ because $a,b > 0$. Thus, $ab$ is bounded above, and $\sup AB$ exists and $\sup AB \leq \alpha\beta$.
We now show $\sup AB \geq \alpha\beta$.
Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $\exists \, a \in A$ s.t. $\alpha - \varepsilon < a \leq \alpha$ and $\exists \, b \in B$ s.t. $\beta - \varepsilon < b \leq \beta$. So:
\begin{equation*}
  (\alpha-\varepsilon)(\beta-\varepsilon) < ab \leq \alpha\beta \qquad \text{ since } \qquad a,b,\varepsilon > 0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  \implies \alpha\beta-\varepsilon(\alpha+\beta-\varepsilon) < ab \leq \alpha\beta
\end{equation*}
But $\varepsilon(\alpha+\beta-\varepsilon)$ has a negative probability when $\varepsilon$ is more than $\alpha+\beta$. How to make sure I get any positive $\varepsilon$ for $\alpha\beta$?

It is enough to consider the case $0<\epsilon <\alpha+\beta$

If this condition is so, it means that we can find $\varepsilon$ large enough, which is no $\exists ab \in Ab$ satisfying $a - \varepsilon (\alpha + \beta - \varepsilon) \leq \alpha \beta$?

Suppose that $A, B\neq\emptyset$. Find $a_n \in A, b_n\in B$ with $a_n \to \sup A$ and $b_n\to \sup B$ and both sequences non-decreasing. Then $a_nb_n$ is a non-decreasing sequence so it has a (finite or infinite) limit $c$.
Clearly we need to have $c\leq \sup AB$ since $a_nb_n\leq \sup AB$ for all $n$. If $a\in A, b\in B$ then since $a\leq \sup A$ and $b\leq \sup B$ there must exist $n$ such that $a\leq a_n$ and $b\leq b_n$, and so $ab \leq a_nb_n\leq c$. This shows that the opposite inequality $\sup AB \leq c$ must also be true. So $c = \sup AB$.
If $\sup A, \sup B\neq 0$, we have $(\sup A)(\sup B) = \lim_n a_n \lim_n b_n = \lim_n a_nb_n = c = \sup AB$.
If $\sup A = 0$ or $\sup B = 0$ then $A = \{0\}$ or $B = \{0\}$ then $AB = \{0\}$, so that $\sup A = 0$ or $\sup B = 0$ and $\sup AB = 0$. Under the convention that $0\cdot \infty = 0$ we again obtain a formula $(\sup A)(\sup B) = \sup AB$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are bounded above, they each have a supremum.
We get
$
   ab < st
  $.
So, AB are bounded above.
Let $ s = \sup A $ and $t = \sup B $. By the definition of supremum, we have:
$
\forall a \in A, \quad a \leq s \quad \text{and} \quad \forall b \in B, \quad b \leq t
$
Now, consider an arbitrarily small $ \epsilon > 0 $. By the property of the supremum, there exist elements $ a \in A $ and $ b \in B $ such that:
$
s - \epsilon < a \quad \text{and} \quad t - \epsilon < b
$
Therefore, we have:
\begin{align*}
(s - \epsilon)(t - \epsilon) &< ab \\
st - \epsilon(s + t) + \epsilon^2 &< ab
\end{align*}
Since $ \epsilon $ is chosen to be arbitrarily small, we know that $ st $ is greater than any product of the form $ ab $ for $ a \in A $ and $ b \in B $, hence
$
\sup (AB) = st
$
Thus, the supremum of the product set $ AB $ cannot be less than $ st $.

$\text{In the final part of you answer, instead of writing}\\color{red}{\text{“since }\epsilon\text{ is chosen to be arbitrarily small, we know that }st\text { is}\\text{greater than any product of the form }ab\text{ for } a \in A\text{ and } b \in B”}\\text{you should write that}\\color{blue}{\text{“since }\epsilon\text{ is chosen to be arbitrarily small, we get that there }\\text{exist }a\in A\text{ and }b\in B\text{ such that }st-\sigma<ab,\text{ for any small}\\text{positive number }\sigma=\epsilon(s+t)-\epsilon^2;”}.$


Prove that $\,\;\sup AB=(\sup A)(\sup B)\;,\;$ where $\;AB\;$ is the product of the sets and $\;A,B\subsetneq\!(0,+\infty)\,$ are bounded above.

Proof :
The thesis is equivalent to the following two claims :
$\begin{align}&\color{blue}{1)\;ab\leqslant(\sup A)(\sup B)\quad\forall\,a\!\in\!A\;\land\;\forall\,b\!\in\!B\;\;;}\\[3pt]&\color{blue}{2)\;\forall\,\varepsilon\!>\!0\;\;\exists\,a_\varepsilon\!\in\!A\;\land\;b_\varepsilon\!\in\!B\;\mid\;a_\varepsilon b_\varepsilon\!>\!(\sup A)(\sup B)\!-\!\varepsilon\,.}\end{align}$
Now we are going to prove the claim $\,1)\,.$
By applying the first property of the supremum, it follows that
$a\leqslant\sup A\quad$ for any $\;a\in A\;\;,$
$b\leqslant\sup B\quad$ for any $\;b\in B\;\;,$
and, since the previous two inequalities only contain positive numbers, we can multiply them side by side and get that
$ab\leqslant(\sup A)(\sup B)\quad\forall\,a\!\in\!A\;\land\;\forall\,b\!\in\!B$
which is the claim $\;1)\,.$
Now we are going to prove the claim $\,2)\,.$
By applying the second property of the supremum of a set, it follows that
for any $\,\varepsilon\!>\!0\,,\;$ in corrispondence to $\;\dfrac{\varepsilon}{\sup A\!+\!\sup B}\!>\!0\;,\;$ there exist $\;a_\varepsilon\!\in\!A\;$ and $\;b_\varepsilon\!\in\!B\;$ such that
$a_\varepsilon>\sup A-\dfrac{\varepsilon}{\sup A\!+\!\sup B}\;\;\;,\qquad\color{blue}{(*)}$
$b_\varepsilon>\sup B-\dfrac{\varepsilon}{\sup A\!+\!\sup B}\;\;\;.\qquad\color{blue}{(**)}$
There are two possible cases :
$\varepsilon<(\sup A)(\sup B)\quad$ or $\quad\varepsilon\geqslant(\sup A)(\sup B)\;.$
If $\;\varepsilon<(\sup A)(\sup B)\;,\;$ then the right-hand sides of the inequalities $\,(*)\,$ and $\,(**)\,$ are both positive, indeed,
$\begin{align}\mathrm{RHS\;}(*)&>\sup A-\dfrac{(\sup A)(\sup B)}{\sup A\!+\!\sup B}=\dfrac{(\sup A)^2}{\sup A\!+\!\sup B}>0\end{align}$
$\begin{align}\mathrm{RHS\;}(**)&>\sup B-\dfrac{(\sup A)(\sup B)}{\sup A\!+\!\sup B}=\dfrac{(\sup B)^2}{\sup A\!+\!\sup B}>0\end{align}$
and, since the inequalities $\,(*)\,$ and $\,(**)\,$ only contain positive numbers, we can multiply them side by side and get that
$\begin{align}a_\varepsilon b_\varepsilon&>(\sup A)(\sup B)-\varepsilon+\dfrac{\varepsilon^2}{\left(\sup A\!+\!\sup B\right)^2}>\\[0pt]&>(\sup A)(\sup B)-\varepsilon\end{align}$
On the other hand, if $\;\varepsilon\geqslant(\sup A)(\sup B)\;,\;$ then we get that
$a_\varepsilon b_\varepsilon>0\geqslant(\sup A)(\sup B)-\varepsilon\;.$
Hence, we have proved in any case that
for all $\;\varepsilon\!>\!0\;$ there exist $\;a_\varepsilon\!\in\!A\;$ and $\;b_\varepsilon\!\in\!B\;$ such that
$a_\varepsilon b_\varepsilon>(\sup A)(\sup B)-\varepsilon$
which is the claim $\;2)\,.$
